# JS Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null given table id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, dom

```
<table id='tabbul' border='1'> <tr>
```

Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null

this is the code where tr is in the proper html format

```
         $('table#tabbul tr:last').after('trhihi/trtrhihi/trtrhihihhi/tr');
```

I am stumped. The function can only be triggered to run after the page is loaded.

Any idea why this is happening?

Also on a sidenote: `$(function(`  and window onready were breaking my code for some reason ( in their correct syntaxes)

Thank you,
Ama

EDIT: MY error was a special freakin character.

Comment: Looks like you `table` element has no proper closing tag

Comment: It does have a proper closing tag?

Comment: full code plz? `trhihi/trtrhihi/trtrhihihhi/tr` should be a valid html tag <tr>something</tr>